# Applying effects to video while capturing in android?

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, ffmpeg

How can i apply effects to video while capturing i am tried in a lot of ways but output is nothing..i have searched and find one Application [VideoFx](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.videofx&hl=en) whaich done what i want..but i didn't get what they are doing..

i have done the applying effects to the image with using `GPUImageProcessing` library..For Applying effects shall i have capture normal video and make it to frames and Apply effects to that frames and again recombine those frames into video..is this is the only process or any other alternatives..Most of the stack answers suggest me `FFMPEG` with using this i get frames from the video ..how to recombine it again??

I think with using this [Camera effects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html) we can apply effects to videos while recording..But i don't know how to apply it with using openGl.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "effects".  For example, in the "Show + capture camera" example in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), you can change the fragment shader to tweak the video.  (A color -> B&W converter is in the code.)  Some effects might be harder to express in GLSL.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a video using frames which you are getting from the ffmpeg. You can find some libraries for making video from frames. Or you can make a Movie from those frmaes and save like video file. You can also treat your frames as raw data and then make a file by adding header to it.

Comment: yeah i know..with using ffmpeg we can divide video into frames..but i want to take the frames while recording video using camera..and diving video into frames and applying effects to each frame and again recombining it into video is takes too much time.